# Переход по ссылке из C++ Builder в браузер с POST авторизацией

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, c++builder, indy

Необходимо перейти в браузер из программы, написанной в С++Builder. Сначала я авторизуюсь на странице, куда планирую попасть:

```
TStringList *SL = new TStringList;
IdHTTP1->HandleRedirects =True;

IdHTTP1->CookieManager = IdCookieManager1;
IdHTTP1->AllowCookies = true;

String Url = "http://host/auth";
SL->Add("login=login");
SL->Add("password=password");

try
{
   Memo1->Text = IdHTTP1->Post(Url, SL);
   ShellExecute(Handle, L"open", L"http://host/auth", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
}
catch(EIdException &E)
{
   ShowMessage("Ошибка:\n" + E.Message + "");
};

delete SL;
```

После авторизации получаю html код нужной мне страницы, который отображается в memo.

Вопрос: Как открыть страницу, на которой уже прошла моя авторизация в браузере? Или как заставить браузер понять, что конечная страница открывается уже авторизованным клиентом?

Comment: а причём тут php?

Comment: А каким образом сервер запоминает авторизацию? Если через какой-нибудь session-id в куки - то вам надо его получить и как-то сохранить в хранилище браузера. Если иначе, то смотреть как. ИМХО проще будет авторизироваться не через инди, а как-то заставить браузер отправить нужный запрос на сервер.